# Ruby Gem vs Site path - LoadError

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, loading, irb

When I was trying to execute my ruby file in *OSX*, I was stuck in this error:

```
in require: cannot load such file -- httparty (LoadError)
```

However, when I tried in the irb

```
require 'httparty'
# => true
```

it returned true. On further investigation, I see that gem environment points to **/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/..** and also the `sudo gem install httparty` installs in this path. However, from the command line when I do: `ruby -e 'puts $LOAD_PATH'` it shows **/Library/Ruby/Site/..** as the path and the `Gems` folder is not included.

I'm running *OSX Mavericks*.

Can anyone let me know why this difference in behavior between `irb` and `gem environment` paths.

Comment: have you use the *bundler*?

Comment: Since Im new to ruby development, Im not sure what exactly you mean by use the bundler. I did try "bundle" after adding the gems that I need in my Gemfile and it said it successfully created. And when I investigated, it had installed the gems in the Ruby/Gems folder. The problem is the path that the $LOAD_PATH refers to. $LOAD_PATH between irb and command line ruby are different

Comment: With bundler if you use the --path command line option, you can specify the directory where you'd like to install the gems. For example: bundle install --path=vendor will install the gems in a directory called vendor in the same directory where you run this command. This will keep gem dependencies of projects independent of each other. When you use bundler, you have to use the bundler commands: Bundler.require to ensure the gems installed in vendor are loaded correctly. If you want to develop with Ruby, I'd suggest spending some time learning Bundler.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.. I will do that.. I was only intrigued why the LOAD_PATH were different between irb and command line ruby.

Comment: The fix to run bundle exec. Got it from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186800/loaderror-by-requiring-a-gem-with-path-or-git